# Formatter in Table -> Label

Tags: sapui5, formatter

i want to dynamically render a table with different types of columns.

This is my structure:

```
var cols = [{
  name: "{i18n>BidNumber}",
  value: "{Items>Dono}"
},{
  name: "{i18n>BidHaulier}",
  value: "{Items>BHaulier}"
},{
  name: "{i18n>BidHaulierName}",
  value: "{Items>BHaulierName}"
},{
  name: "{i18n>BidContact}",
  value: "{Items>Contact}"
},{
  name: "{i18n>BidPostingDate}",
  value: "{Items>BRunoffti}",
  formatter: "formatter.getDateShort"
}];
```

And here is my loop for building the columns

```
var colItems = new sap.m.ColumnListItem("colItems",{type:"Active"});                    
for(var i = 0; i < cols.length; i ++){
   var txtNAME = new sap.m.Label({
       text: {
            path: cols[i].value,
            formatter:  cols[i].formatter
        }
    });
    colItems.addCell(txtNAME); 
}
```

In my rendered view i got empty columns and the formatter isn't called.

This one, without the formatter, works for me:

```
var colItems = new sap.m.ColumnListItem("colItems",{type:"Active"});     
for(var i = 0; i < cols.length; i ++){
   var txtNAME = new sap.m.Label({text: cols[i].value });
   colItems.addCell(txtNAME); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you do somthing like this:

```
var colItems = new sap.m.ColumnListItem("colItems",{type:"Active"});     
for(var i = 0; i < cols.length; i ++){
   var txtNAME = new sap.m.Label({
       text: { path: cols[i].value,
               formatter: formatter.getDateShort
             }
   });
   colItems.addCell(txtNAME); 
}
```

in this case I think you should remove curly brackets from your cols array:

```
var cols = [{
  name: "{i18n>BidNumber}",
  value: "Items>Dono"
}
```